# Matlab Bar Plot with multiple X-Axis

Tags: matlab, user-interface, bar-chart

i've been struggling with this for some time.

i want to be able to plot the following example **except** while using a bar plot.

[simple plot that needs to be converted to bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZTST.png)

this was implemented by myself. This is basically two plot overlay each other with a different axes each (current example shows the same ticks values but i want them to be changes later on)

my problem is that using bar plot changes axis location like so and i cannot resolve it. see image below:

[desired image but lower axis are not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43bz6.png)

The axes here are not aligned. i need both to start at the same place, that is the most left bar

your help is much appreciated
my code below:

```
close all
figure
y= magic(10)
a=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7],'XColor','b');
%                 hold on;
bar( y(1,:),'b','DisplayName','before prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
xticklabels( {3:12});
legend;


hold on
bar(y(2,:),'r','DisplayName','after prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
b= axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 1e-12],'XColor','r')
xticklabels( {4:13});
legend;
```

EDIT:
managed to solve it - see update code below

```
close all
figure
y= magic(10)
ax1=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7],'XColor','b');
bar(  y(1,:),'b','DisplayName','before prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
ax = gca
xticklabels( {3:12});
legend;


hold on
bar(y(2,:),'r','DisplayName','after prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
axPos = ax1.Position;
ax2 = axes('Position', (axPos .* [1 1 1 1e-3])-[0 .07 0 -1e-3]  , 'XColor', 'r', 'linewidth', 2);

 set(ax2,'XLim',[-0.2 11.2])
set(ax2,'XTick',(1:10))
 xticklabels( {4:13});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use same x-limit for two bar plots. The MATLAB function is 'xlim'.

```
figure
y= magic(10)
a=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7],'XColor','b'); hold all;
bar( y(1,:),'b','DisplayName','before prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
xticks(3:1:12); xlim([0 15]) 
legend;

bar(y(2,:),'r','DisplayName','after prop','FaceAlpha',0.1);
b= axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 1e-12],'XColor','r'); xlim([3 12]);
xticks(4:1:13); xlim([0 15]) 
legend;
```

Comment: Managed to solve the issue . thank you!
i've updated the question with the updated code